# Runtime tar.gz browsing

Tags: php

I have PHP code that uses random assets and I want to get them from tar.gz file without unpacking it at runtime.

Is there any way to do it? (Of course: I can unpack it, but why? I just want single image and base64 it (there are different images; this is just example)).

Comment: You have to "unpack" it, be it to disk or in memory. How will you know where your image is in data without first decompressing it. The reason the file has two extensions is because two things have been applied. 1) tar, and 2) gzip. These are separate operations, it's not like a zip file where the whole directory structure is indexed.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Disk space is extremely cheap these days.

Comment: It's for the purpose of fast deployment of my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no sensible, efficient way to do so. Neither TAR nor Gzip support random access, so you'd have to decompress and scan through the whole thing to access any element within the archive. This would be extremely slow.

Use something like ZIP if you need random access to compressed data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to call `tar` to extract single files of your archive in memory:

For Example:

```
z.tgz -> contains two files 1.txt and 2.txt
```

Then this gets you the contents of `1.txt` into a variable.

```
<?php
    $file='z.tgz';
    $extract='1.txt';

    $fp=popen('tar Oxzf '.$file.' '.$extract,'r');
    if (!$fp) die('Failed to execute tar');
    $data=stream_get_contents($fp);
    fclose($fp);
    echo 'Contents of '.$extract.': '.$data;
?>
```